# Whas is the difference between the `has` and `contains` operators in KQL?

Tags: azure, kql

Whas is the difference between the `has` and `contains` operators in KQL?

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-operator) is the `has` operator documentation. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/contains-operator) is the documentation for the `contains` operator.

Both of them check for an existence of a case insensitive string. So, does it mean that the usage of one operator over the other is just a matter of taste?

Comment: The first paragraph of each states the differences, and the [quick ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kql-quick-reference) has (contains?) a shorter summary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- *contains* will always return true if the searched string exists within the searched text.
- *has* result depends on the surrounding of the searched string within the searched text.

Why should we prefer *has* over *contains* in some scenarios?
TL;DR: performance (use of index vs. data scan).

---

A term is a sequence of alpha-numeric characters (see [What is a term?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators#what-is-a-term)).

Some examples:

- *1Hello2World*, *Z* & *42* are all terms.
- *Hello-World*, *Hello_World* & *Hello World*, are all constructed of 2 terms.
- *056c8e97-422f-4e29-836b-ec3b0d77a50b* (an example for GUID) is constructed of 5 terms.
- *!@#$%^&*()* has no terms

Azure Data Explorer (AKA ADX, AKA Kusto), indexes every term, as long it is 3 characters long or more (for storage engine v3. For v2 it is 4 characters).
The index (Full-text search index) is what enables ADX to return search results in sub-seconds/seconds even when the searched is done on Petabytes.
As of today, the index can be used for a whole term search, or for a prefix search.

Here are how *contains* & *has* behave for different searched strings:

- *ell*

  - *contains* finds the searched string within texts such as *ell*, *Hell*, *Ella*, *HELLO*, *7ell8* & *(.ell.)*, yielding a data scan (not using the index).
  - *has* finds the searched string within texts such as *ell*, *Ell*, *ELL*, & *(.ell.)*, leveraging the index.
    *has* does not find the searched string if it is contained within a longer term (e.g., *bell*, *Ella* or *Hello*)
- *el*

  - Similar to the example above, however both operators do not use the index since the index contains only terms of 3 characters or more.
- *#ell#*

  - Both operators return the same results.
  - Both operators leverage the index (whole term search) for an initial filtering on the term (*ell*), followed by a narrowed data scan (to filter out on the entire searched string).
- *#ell*

  - *contains* finds the searched string within texts such as *#ell*, *@#Ell#@*, *#Ella* etc.
  - *has* finds the searched string within texts such as *#ell* & *@#Ell#@*.
    *has* does not find the searched string if the term (*ell*) is a prefix of a longer term (e.g., *Ella*).
  - Both operators leverage the index (*has* performs whole term search while *contains* perform prefix search) for an initial filtering on the term (*ell*), followed by a narrowed data scan (to filter out on the entire searched string).
  - In this context *hasprefix* will behave exactly like *contains.
- *ell#*

  - *contains* finds the searched string within texts such as *ell#*, *@#Ell#@*, *Hell#* etc.
  - *has* finds the searched string within texts such as *ell#* & *@#Ell#@*.
    *has* does not find the searched string if the term (*ell*) is a suffix of a longer term (e.g., *Cell*).
    *has* leverage the index while *contains* does not.
  - In this context *hassuffix* will behave exactly like *contains.

P.S.
Even if a term is indexed, the index might not be used, e.g., when a term is highly common, scanning the data itself directly might be cheaper than using the index.

Here are some examples for search strings that are found by *contains* and not by *has*.
Note the following:

- *contains* always finds the searched substring (`hell` or `hello`).
- *has* never finds the substring `hell`.
- *has* finds the searched substring `hello`as long as it is not a part of a longer alpha-numeric sequence.

```
datatable(txt:string)
[
    "Hello World"
   ,"<Hello-World>"
   ,"*Hello*World*"
   ,"?Hello%World!"
   ,"_Hello_World_"
   ,"123Hello-World456"
   ,"abcHello Worldxyz"
   ,"HelloWorld"
]
| extend contains_hell  = txt contains  "hell"
        ,contains_hello = txt contains  "hello"
        ,has_hell       = txt has       "hell"
        ,has_hello      = txt has       "hello"
```

| txt | contains_hell | contains_hello | has_hell | has_hello |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hello World | true | true | false | true |
| <Hello-World> | true | true | false | true |
| *Hello*World* | true | true | false | true |
| ?Hello%World! | true | true | false | true |
| *Hello_World* | true | true | false | true |
| 123Hello-World456 | true | true | false | false |
| abcHello Worldxyz | true | true | false | false |
| HelloWorld | true | true | false | false |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA33PSwrCMBAG4H2gdxgDgpa68LkQH1tv4EIkpG2whZCBNosoHt44daSiOFnly59JptQ%20rtyakQ9%203fqmdpdxIk6JgFjyYKxFOGJjS0mUyQ3ZhGzHmBKmhCnjnnBIOGBUhIpQMU5n817XxXLFBzovel8I1xsfkPK/zom4gwneuBIKdF7XrlVVTABsIc71xjjRk7smVNlHHn/nsX%20h0tybqrsQ8bX/eoDz%20CeP8gHw9V0RiAEAAA==)